# How can I pass an object array from one component to another?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tried every way I've seen on internet, but it is impossible. When I write a console log on the other component, it says it's undefined.

(Its an object array btw)

This is from the first component:

```
  irAlCarrito():void{
let params = {queryParams: this.carrito};
this.router.navigate(['/carrito', params]);
```

}

This is from the second component:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
this.router.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => this.carrito = params.getAll("carrito"));
console.log(this.carrito[0]);
```

}

Comment: Do you see the (correct) queryParams in the url..?

Comment: I see this: /carrito;queryParams=%5Bobject%20Object%5D

Comment: @LuisRosúa is my solution working for you?

Answer (score 0):

three mistakes here

the first you must send string, not array or object for this we will make it `JSON.stringify`

the second, you must add a key for your value and not to pass it directly

the third, you queryParams should be send as a second param to navigate not as a second item in the routing array

here is the full working code

```
let params = {queryParams: {carrito: JSON.stringify(this.carrito)}};
this.router.navigate(['/carrito'], params);
```